# Joining two entities where both have composite primary key, and we need to join using part of primary key using spring data jpa

Tags: spring-data-jpa, composite-primary-key, jpa-2.1

I have two entities which has separate composite primary keys, Example :-

```
@Entity
public class Payment
{
   @EmbeddedId
   private PaymentPK pk1;
   private BigInteger amount;
   private String countryCode;
}

@Embeddable
public class PaymentPK implements Serializable {
    private Long transactionId;
    private String type;
}

@Entity
public class tax
{
   @EmbeddedId
   private TaxPK pk2;
   private BigInteger amount;
   private String countryCode;
}

@Embeddable
public class TaxPK implements Serializable {
    private Long transactionId;
    private String taxType;
}
```

I want to add relationship @ManyToOne, where every payment transaction can have multiple taxes applied to it. The problem here is both entities have different PK, So join on FK is not working(As per my understanding of JPA it allows join on composite key not on part of it). Please help me how to achieve it.I want join based on transactionId attribute.